# mybatis assocation returns only a list with size one?

Tags: java, mybatis

Below is my mapper xml.

```
<mapper namespace="/">
    <resultMap id="JiKeAuthorMap" type="Author">
        <id property="id" column="author.id" />
        <result property="realName" column="realName" />
        <result property="IDCard" column="IDCard" />
        <association property="jikeUser" column="userID"
            javaType="JiKeUser" >
            <id property="id" column="jikeUser.id" />
            <result property="userName" column="userName" />
            <result property="password" column="password" />
        </association>

    </resultMap>

    <select id="selectAuthorJoin" resultMap="JiKeAuthorMap">
        select * from author   join jikeUser 
            on jikeuser.id=author.userID
    </select>
</mapper>
```

below is the table **author**

SELECT * FROM author;

```
    id  realName      userID  IDCard  
------  ------------  ------  --------
     3  cccccc             3  (NULL)  
     2  bbb                2  (NULL)  
     1  dddddd             8  (NULL)
```

below is the table **JiKeUser**

SELECT * FROM JiKeUser;

```
    id  userName   password  
------  ---------  ----------
     2  jike00100  666666    
     3  jike00200  888888    
     8  author001  123456
```

below is the main code of java pojo.(author have a reference to jikeUser)

```
public class Author {
    private Integer id; // 
    private JiKeUser jikeUser; //reference to JiKeUser table
```

Then I use below code to execute the 'select'.The size is only one.

```
    List<Author> ap=session.selectList("selectAuthorJoin"); 
    System.out.println(ap.size());   //1
```

But actually the size should be three. You can see below.

```
SELECT * FROM author INNER JOIN jikeUser 
            ON jikeuser.id=author.userID ;
    id  realName  userID  IDCard      id  userName   password  
------  --------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  ----------
     2  bbb            2  (NULL)       2  jike00100  666666    
     3  cccccc         3  (NULL)       3  jike00200  888888    
     1  dddddd         8  (NULL)       8  author001  123456
```

But it's werid that my code only return the first line like below.

```
 id  realName  userID  IDCard      id  userName   password  
    ------  --------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  ----------
         2  bbb            2  (NULL)       2  jike00100  666666
```

Comment: If you need all results from the query as stated above what is the need to have a bean `JiKeUser` for the table instead you can use `getters and setters` for `username and password` in the `author` bean itself and remove the `association property` and replace it with `result property` and on the other hand you could simply return list of `linked hashmap` by avoiding writing `pojos` .

Answer (score 0):

try replace

`<id property="id" column="author.id" />`

to

`<result property="id" column="author.id" />`

to see [MyBatis collection in association only return one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320836/mybatis-collection-in-association-only-return-one-row)

its use for me.